# Get CN value from ADUser DistinguishedName

Tags: powershell, active-directory, distinguishedname

I have a PS script that checks some custom user's properties in Active Directory.
One of the properties is "Manager".

```
 $data = Get-ADUser $user -Properties * |  Select-Object DisplayName, LockedOut, Enabled, LastLogonDate, PasswordExpired, EmailAddress, Company, Title, Manager, Office

 Write-Host "9." $user "manager is" $data.manager -ForegroundColor Green
```

When I run the script I've got:

```
User's manager is CN=cool.boss,OU=Users,OU=SO,OU=PL,OU=RET,OU=HBG,DC=domain,DC=com
```

The problem is that text `"OU=SO,OU=PL,OU=RET,OU=HBG,DC=domain,DC=com"` will be different for some users

How can I modify output and remove everything except `"cool.boss"`?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be a more or less safe and still easy way to parse it:

```
($data.manager -split "," | ConvertFrom-StringData).CN
```

Comment: (Sorry, I had misread the question - your answer is on point). +1 for an elegant solution whose only limitation is  that _escaped_ commas embedded in values (`\,`), which probably aren't common, wouldn't be handled correctly.

Comment: Very slick method for parsing `CN` +1.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes that's what I meant with "more or less" ;) Thanks for your answer though, a good reference in case someone needs a fully featured solution some time.

Answer (score 3):

To complement the helpful answers here with PowerShell-idiomatic [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) solutions:

- Using `-split`, the regex-based [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split):

```sh
$dn = 'CN=cool.boss,OU=Users,OU=SO,OU=PL,OU=RET,OU=HBG,DC=domain,DC=com'

($dn -split '(?:^|,)CN=|,')[1] # -> 'cool.boss'
```

- Using `-replace`, the regex-based [string substitution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

```sh
$dn = 'CN=cool.boss,OU=Users,OU=SO,OU=PL,OU=RET,OU=HBG,DC=domain,DC=com'

$dn -replace '(?:^|,)CN=([^,]+).*', '$1' # -> 'cool.boss'
```

Note:

- The above solutions do not rely on a specific order of the name-value pairs (RDNs) in the input (that is, a `CN` entry needn't be the *first* one), but they do extract only the *first* `CN` entry's value, should multiple ones be present, and they do assume that (at least) one is present.
- In principle, [DNs (Distinguished Names)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names), of which the input string is an example, can have `,` characters *embedded* in the values of the name-value pairs that make up a DN, escaped as `\,` (or, in hex notation, `\2C`); e.g., `"CN=boss\, cool,OU=Users,..."`
- A truly robust solution would have to take that into account, and would ideally also *unescape* the resulting value; none of the existing answers do that as of this writing; see below.

---

**Robustly parsing an LDAP/AD DN ([Distinguished Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names))**:

The following **`Split-DN` function**:

- handles *escaped, embedded* `,` chars., as well as other escape sequences, correctly
- *unescapes* the values, which includes not just removing syntactic `\`, but also converting escape sequences in the form `\<hh>`, where `hh` is a two-digit hex. number representing a character's code point, to the actual character they represent (e.g, `\3C`, is converted to a `<` character).
- outputs an ordered [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) whose keys are the name components (e.g., `CN`, `OU`), with the values for names that occur *multiple* times - such as `OU` - represented as an *array*.

**Example call:**

```
PS> Split-DN 'CN=I \3C3 Huckabees\, I do,OU=Users,OU=SO,OU=PL,OU=RET,OU=HBG,DC=domain,DC=com'

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CN                             I <3 Huckabees, I do
OU                             {Users, SO, PL, RET…}
DC                             {domain, com}
```

Note how escape sequence `\3C` was converted to `<`, the character it represents, and how `\,` was recognized as an `,` *embedded* in the `CN` value.

Since the input string contained *multiple* `OU` and `DC` name-value pairs (so-called RDNs, *relative* distinguished names), their corresponding hashtable entries became *arrays* of values (signified in the truncated-for-display-only output with `{ ... }`, with `,` separating the elements).

---

**Function `Split-DN`'s source code:**

Note: For brevity, error handling and validation are omitted.

```
function Split-DN {

  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $DN
  )

  # Initialize the (ordered) output hashtable.
  $oht = [ordered] @{}

  # Split into name-value pairs, while correctly recognizing escaped, embedded
  # commas.
  $nameValuePairs = $DN -split '(?<=(?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*),'

  $nameValuePairs.ForEach({

    # Split into name and value.
    # Note: Names aren't permitted to contain escaped chars.
    $name, $value = ($_ -split '=', 2).Trim()

    # Unescape the value, if necessary.
    if ($value -and $value.Contains('\')) {
      $value = [regex]::Replace($value, '(?i)\\(?:[0-9a-f]){2}|\\.', {
        $char = $args[0].ToString().Substring(1)
        if ($char.Length -eq 1) { # A \<literal-char> sequence.
          $char # Output the character itself, without the preceding "\"
        }
        else { # A \<hh> escape sequence, conver the hex. code point to a char.
          [char] [uint16]::Parse($char, 'AllowHexSpecifier') 
        }
      })
    }
    
    # Add an entry to the output hashtable. If one already exists for the name,
    # convert the existing value to an array, if necessary, and append the new value.
    if ($existingEntry = $oht[$name]) {
      $oht[$name] = ([array] $existingEntry) + $value
    }
    else {
      $oht[$name] = $value
    }

  })

  # Output the hashtable.
  $oht
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.split()` method to get what you want.

```
$DN = "CN=cool.boss,OU=Users,OU=SO,OU=PL,OU=RET,OU=HBG,DC=domain,DC =com"
$DN.Split(',').Split('=')[1]
```

What i'd recommend, is throwing it into another `Get-ADUser` to get the displayname for neater output(:

Answer (score 1):

you could use regex for that:

```
$s = "CN=cool.boss,OU=Users,OU=SO,OU=PL,OU=RET,OU=HBG,DC=domain,DC =com"

$pattern = [regex]"CN=.*?OU"
$r = $pattern.Replace($s, "CN=OU")
$r
```