# Powershell Where-Object Subject -Match with split to exclude CN= etc?

Tags: powershell, split

How can i split my output from undesired "content" for example

`Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\CA | Where-Object Subject -Match "Windows"`

i get subject looking like this

> CN=Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility, OU=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Intermediate CA, OU=Copy....

How can i display only content without *"CN="* , *"OU="* but only like this, in a one-liner:

> Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Microsoft Corporation Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Intermediate CA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
Clear-Host
(
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\CA' | 
    Where-Object Subject -Match 'Windows'
).Subject -replace  ',|.[A-Z]='
# Results
<#
Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Microsoft Corporation Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Intermediate CA Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft 
Corp.
#>
```

Comment: Yes it seems to be working just as i wanted. I will try it out as an variable and see what happens when i test the code in a computerarray and see what happens. But works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to extract the field *values* from a DN (Distinguished Name).

[postanote's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73597133/45375) *somewhat* does that, but, due to returning a single string with spaces as the separator, the boundaries between the field values are lost.

If you want to retrieve the field values as an *array* of strings, use the [`regex::Matches()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) .NET method; you can convert the array to a single-line representation with a separator of choice using `-join` later:

```bash
# Outputs the field values as an *array*
[regex]::Matches(
  (Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\CA | Where-Object Subject -Match Windows).Subject, 
  '(?<==)[^,]+'
).Value
```

A simplified example, using [`-join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) with a custom separator:

```bash
[regex]::Matches(
  'CN=common name, OU=org unit 1, OU=org unit 2', 
  '(?<==)[^,]+'
).Value -join '|'
```

Verbatim output:

```bash
common name|org unit 1|org unit 2
```

If separator-based single-line output is the *only* goal, you can simplify to a single [`-replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation (same output as above):

```bash
(
  'CN=common name, OU=org unit 1, OU=org unit 2' -replace 
    '(?:^|, )[a-z]+=', '|'
).Substring(1)
```

*Caveat*: like postanote's answer, this **assumes that no field value contains *escaped* `,` or `=` characters in the form of `\,` or `\=`**.
A more complex regex would be required to account for that, such as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67506093/45375).

Comment: ''mklement0', agreed, and I originally started down this path (still using a simple replace ***-replace  '.[A-Z]=' -replace ',\s', '|'***) but changed to what I provided, specifically what the OP showed as their desired output.

Comment: Understood, @postanote. My aim was to point out the limitation of a single-line representation based on spaces as the separators, and to provide a solution that overcomes this limitation. 
I see that the solution in your previous comment would also work to produce a single-line representation with a custom separator with the specific DN (Distinguished Name) at hand,
which only has _two-character_ field names. Generally speaking, however, this is not true of all field names - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names).

Comment: @postanote, you could overcome the latter limitation with something like `('CN=common name, OU=org unit 1, OU=org unit 2' -replace '(?:^|, )[a-z]+=', '|').Substring(1)`, though the caveat with respect to not handling _escaped_ characters correctly still applies.

Comment: Agreed adn copy that, regarding the escape char thing.